# What clear substance could be sprayed on RJ45 Ethernet terminals?

Tags: ethernet, cable

As installed by Verizon, the cat5e/cat6 cable does not plug directly into the Ethernet port of the unit.

Instead, there are terminals for each wire pair (see photo).

If one were to open the snap-close terminals, one would find that a clear substance (slightly sticky, a little viscous, been applied to each terminal, perhaps as an oxidation inhibitor or to keep dust out.

What would the clear substance likely be?  I seem to recall the Verizon technician applying it when he installed it several years ago.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here, as are question about networks you do not directly control. You need to as Verizon about that.

Comment: By the way, that cannot be Category-6 or even 5e because the cabling would never pass the category test. The pairs are simply too untwisted to pass a proper category test.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think technically the kind of terminal could exist anywhere, in a commercial setting.  I learned the POTS pairs exist to allow field technicians who have more familiarity with POTS to connect the other end of the wire.  The patch cable actually comes with one end already on it.

Comment: PS Thank you for letting me know the rules.  I’ll endeavor to ask either more general questions or as you say, not about networks I don’t control etc.  Here I was really just curious about what you could protect terminals with, and that seems within the rules (maybe not with a photo though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a block for POTS pairs. I don't know why they have your ethernet running through it.

The goo is a silicone dielectric sealant. (google it)

Comment: Thanks!  My research suggests that it’s a weird cost saving method to allow field technicians to only carry one set of equipment (and use cables that are pre-crimped in one end only).

Comment: When all you have is a hammer, everything is a nail. (RJ crimp tools and crimps are far cheaper than those junction blocks. A good crimper is ~100$ and you'll use it for centuries. Crimps are $0.25. The *knowledge* to use them is the real thing telcos won't invest in.)